# Count Times and Usages Statistic of an Specific Android Application through another Android Application

Tags: android, android-service

Suppose "X" android application want to track how many times user open "Y" android application and how many times he spend using that application. 
So, my question is

1)Is that possible ?

2)If possible, then how I can get usages information's ?

Answer (score 0):

// there is an in build functionality in android

open your phone dialer and type the below code

```
*#*#4636#*#*
```

then you will get and Testing view in that

Select `Usage statistics`